# PHP script PDO doesn't use password when run with apache, but does when run in another script

Tags: php, mysql, apache, pdo

I have a php script that was working fine before a version upgrade to v8.0.3 from 5.3. Here is the line at fault

```
include '/var/www/secure/all_duh_creds.php';
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=host;port=3306;dbname=db",'root',$sched_password);
```

Here is the relevant line in all_duh_creds.php

```
$sched_password = getenv('SCHED_PASSWORD');
```

Running env I see

```
SCHED_PASSWORD=password
```

Running a php script which uses this PDO connection I don't receive an error, but

```
httpd -D FOREGROUND
```

doesn't connect. When I navigate to the main page it's blank and this is in the log

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'172.17.0.11' (using password: NO) in.../db.php:3
Stack trace:
```

I haven't been able to find out why it's not using the password. I imagine that the env is removed

Comment: ___version upgrade___ Bit vague, what did you upgrade

Comment: Corrected to include the changes in version.

Comment: Thats quite a jump!

Comment: @RiggsFolly regrettably ya. It hasn't really been touched since I was in middle school and before I knew the horror of version compatibility . :D

Comment: So did you test a simple little script that just does `echo getenv('SCHED_PASSWORD');`

Comment: @RiggsFolly I just tried with apache. When loaded in the browser it is blank, but when run php file/path it returns the proper result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is from the fact apache won't set environment variables from the profile. Therefore when the script is initiated by Apache it won't see the variable. You can SetEnv or PassEnv

Solution, in your httpd.conf add:

```
PassEnv SCHED_PASSWORD
```

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_env.html